# How to reverse the levels of a numeric vector

Tags: r, object, vector, reverse

I have a vector with 47 numeric objects, values of objects from 1 to 7.

```
df$PS<- 2 3 7 4 5 3 7 3 7 3 1 6 3 6 3 3 1 5 1 3 3 1 3 2 3 5 3 5 4 4 2 1 4 3 5 3 2 4 4 3 7 3 6 4 1 6 2
```

I need to reverse objects' values so that 1 becomes 7, 2 becomes 6, and so on. My code didn't work. I tried to assign reverse value to objects with a certain value

```
df$PS[df$PS==1] <- 7
```

but it didn't work

I think I found out how to make it work - use the function replace

Comment: Welcome to SO, user22985482! I think you're asking about replacing all values at once, where doing it one-value-at-a-time might fall into the case where the new values of one reassignment are not distinguished from the old values of another. There are likely a few ways to work with this, but your question would be considerably easier to answer with sample data. Please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(PS,30))` into a [code block] (`30` is a balance between "enough to closely represent" and "too much").

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions on how best to share unambiguous, sample, representative data using `dput`, `data.frame`, `read.table`, or other techniques. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just do `8 - df$PS` ?

Comment: Please always check the code you provide for the data. Did you even try to run the line `df$PS <- 2 3 7 4 5 3`? This is not proper R code. Are you trying to use `df$PS <- c(2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 3......)`?

Comment: I just gave an example of my vector

Answer (score 1):

Various ways:

```
vec <- rep(1:7, 2)

dplyr::dense_rank(-vec)
[1] 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

---

```
max(vec) - vec + 1
[1] 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

---

```
match(vec, sort(unique(vec), TRUE))
[1] 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

---

Answer (score 0):

We can create an named index with the `rev`ersed levels of the vector.
Then splice (`!!!`) the index inside `recode`

```
#example data
vector <- rep(1:7, 2)

vector
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

# create the index with reversed levels
levels <- 1:7
index <- setNames(rev(levels), levels)
index
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 

# recode the values
recode(vector, !!!index)
 [1] 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```